# My robot frame work suite setup __init__.robot does not run

Tags: robotframework

I have this setup

__init__.robot:

```
*** Settings *** Suite Setup    Init
*** Keywords ***
Init
    Log  Initialization   console= true`
```

test.robot:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Case1
Log  test case 1   console=true
```

suite.txt:

```
test.robot
```

when I run 
pybot  --argumentfile suite.txt

my __init__.robot does not run. 
How do I get it run?

Answer (score 4):

Robot does not executes __init__.robot when executing one file inside folder with __init__.robot.

Consider that your files are under /TestSuite/, run following to see the changes:

```
pybot /TestSuite  (this will execute everything inside TestSuite with __init__ )

pybot -s test -t Case1 /TestSuite (this will execute suite test.robot and only selected test Case1 from folder TestSuite together with __init__ )

pybot -t Case1 /TestSuite/test.robot (this will execute only Case1 from test.robot without __init__ )
```

RobotFramework Docs for the rescue:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-flow